# React testing hook with callback

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, react-testing-library

I'm trying to test a simple hook i've made for intercepting offline/online events:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useOfflineDetection = (
  setOffline: (isOffline: boolean) => void
): void => {
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('offline', () => setOffline(true));
    window.addEventListener('online', () => setOffline(false));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('offline', () => setOffline(true));
      window.removeEventListener('online', () => setOffline(false));
    };
  }, []);
};

export default useOfflineDetection;

------------------------------------

//...somewhere else in the code

useOfflineDetection((isOffline: boolean) => Do something with 'isOffline');
```

But I'm not sure I'm using the correct way to return value and moreover I'm not sure to get how to test it with jest, @testing-library & @testing-library/react-hooks.

I missunderstand how to mount my hook and then catch the return provide by callback.

Is someone can help me ? I'm stuck with it :'(

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**

Like Estus Flask said, I can use useEffect instead callback like I design it first.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const useOfflineDetection = (): boolean => {
  const [isOffline, setIsOffline] = useState<boolean>(false);
  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('offline', () => setIsOffline(true));
    window.addEventListener('online', () => setIsOffline(false));

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('offline', () => setIsOffline(true));
      window.removeEventListener('online', () => setIsOffline(false));
    };
  }, []);

  return isOffline;
};

export default useOfflineDetection;

------------------------------------

//...somewhere else in the code

const isOffline = useOfflineDetection();

Do something with 'isOffline'
```

But if I want to use this hook in order to store "isOffline" with something like redux or other, the only pattern I see it's using useEffect:

```
const isOffline = useOfflineDetection();
useEffect(() => {
   dispatch(setIsOffline(isOffline));
}, [isOffline])
```

instead of just:

```
useOfflineDetection(isOffline => dispatch(setIsOffline(isOffline)));
```

But is it that bad ?

Comment: Btw a more idiomatic way to implement this would be useState instead of setOffline callback. It would be a little bit simpler to test too.

Comment: That was how I made it first. But I try to design it to be used with redux or by using a "local" state. If I want to dispatch this state, the only pattern I see it's by using useEffect on "setOffline" state returned by the hook. If you have another pattern in mind...

Comment: Keeping Redux into account looks like overengineering in this case, unless this is specifically how you use this hook. Redux state is commonly global and could implement such thing without a need to be coupled with React component. What you showed with useState is the way this is commonly done in custom hooks.

Comment: Yeap you probably got right, I think I want to try something too "complicated" for my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with the hook is that clean up will fail because `addEventListener` and `removeEventListener` callbacks are different. They should be provided with the same functions:

```
const setOfflineTrue = useCallback(() => setOffline(true), []);
const setOfflineFalse = useCallback(() => setOffline(false), []);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('offline', setOfflineTrue);
  ...
```

Then React Hooks Testing Library can be used to test a hook.

Since DOM event targets have determined behaviour that is supported by Jest DOM to some extent, respective events can be dispatched to test a callback:

```
const mockSetOffline = jest.fn();
const wrapper = renderHook(() => useOfflineDetection(mockSetOffline));

expect(mockSetOffline).not.toBeCalled();

// called only on events
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('offline'));
expect(mockSetOffline).toBeCalledTimes(1);
expect(mockSetOffline).lastCalledWith(false);

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('online'));
expect(mockSetOffline).toBeCalledTimes(2);
expect(mockSetOffline).lastCalledWith(true);

// listener is registered once
wrapper.rerender();
expect(mockSetOffline).toBeCalledTimes(2);

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('offline'));
expect(mockSetOffline).toBeCalledTimes(3);
expect(mockSetOffline).lastCalledWith(false);

window.dispatchEvent(new Event('online'));
expect(mockSetOffline).toBeCalledTimes(4);
expect(mockSetOffline).lastCalledWith(true);

// cleanup is done correctly
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('offline'));
window.dispatchEvent(new Event('online'));
expect(mockSetOffline).toBeCalledTimes(4);
```

Comment: Clean and understanding, thanks a lot for your time :)